Linux can't use network devices
I run a dual boot with Ubuntu 24 and Windows 11. Recently I had a problem where after using the Windows partition, I could login to Linux but was met with a black screen. I'm pretty sure this was related to Windows fast boot not fully powering down my graphics card. I was able to resolve that problem, but now, when I login to Linux, neither my Ethernet connection nor my Wireless card are detected. The kernel seems to recognize both devices, but I can't ping anything and NetworkManager doesn't have any devices managed. If I boot Windows or open a fresh install of Linux from a USB, everything seems fine network-wise. Can someone help me regain access to the Internet?
Edit: The results of ip address:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

The return from sudo lshw was too long for this question, but I believe this is the relevant part:
 *-network UNCLAIMED
         description: Network controller
         product: Raptor Lake-S PCH CNVi WiFi
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
         version: 11
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:42f14000-42f17fff
    *-serial:0 UNCLAIMED
         description: Serial bus controller
         product: Raptor Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller #0
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 15
         bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
         version: 11
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:40600000-40600fff
    *-serial:1 UNCLAIMED
         description: Serial bus controller
         product: Raptor Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 15.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:15.1
         version: 11
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:40601000-40601fff
    *-serial:2 UNCLAIMED
         description: Serial bus controller
         product: Raptor Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller #2
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 15.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:15.2
         version: 11
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:40602000-40602fff
    *-serial:3 UNCLAIMED
         description: Serial bus controller
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 15.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:15.3
         version: 11
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:40603000-40603fff
    *-communication UNCLAIMED
         description: Communication controller
         product: Raptor Lake CSME HECI #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 16
         bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
         version: 11
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:42f23000-42f23fff

and a little later:
*-pci:3
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Raptor Lake PCI Express Root Port #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
         version: 11
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:123 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:42200000-42bfffff ioport:40400000(size=2097152)
    *-pci:4
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
         version: 11
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:124 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:42c00000-42cfffff
       *-network UNCLAIMED
            description: Ethernet controller
            product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
            version: 05
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
            configuration: latency=0
            resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:42c00000-42c0ffff memory:42c10000-42c13fff
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: Raptor Lake LPC/eSPI Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
         version: 11
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master
         configuration: latency=0
       *-pnp00:00
            product: PnP device PNP0c02
            physical id: 0
            capabilities: pnp
            configuration: driver=system
       *-pnp00:01
            product: PnP device PNP0c02
            physical id: 1
            capabilities: pnp
            configuration: driver=system
       *-pnp00:02
            product: PnP device PNP0c02
            physical id: 2
            capabilities: pnp
            configuration: driver=system
       *-pnp00:03
            product: PnP device PNP0c02
            physical id: 3
            capabilities: pnp
            configuration: driver=system
       *-pnp00:04
            product: PnP device PNP0c02
            physical id: 4
            capabilities: pnp
            configuration: driver=system
       *-pnp00:05
            product: PnP device PNP0c02
            physical id: 5
            capabilities: pnp
            configuration: driver=system
       *-pnp00:06
            product: PnP device PNP0c02
            physical id: 6
            capabilities: pnp
            configuration: driver=system


Can you please provide a bit more information on the Linux side: An ip -a would help along with something like lspci or lshw Welcome to AskUbuntu!

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please use these commands in the terminal as requested in the above comment. Then copy the output from the terminal and paste then directly into your question. Then format the pasted text as code using the {_} icon above the edit window.
